# function error for python-rsa module

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, rsa

i installed [Python-RSA](https://stuvel.eu/rsa) for using rsa algorithm in my python project , but when i want to use it i have this error :

[image: run error]

```
import rsa
(public_key, private_key) = rsa.newkeys(1024, accurate=True, poolsize=8)
```

Above code is from [official Doc](https://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/usage.html)

i check module files for **newkeys()** function and this function exists

[image: module's files]

```
def newkeys(nbits, accurate=True, poolsize=1):
    if nbits < 16:
        raise ValueError('Key too small')
    if poolsize < 1:
        raise ValueError('Pool size (%i) should be >= 1' % poolsize)
    if poolsize > 1:
        from rsa import parallel
        import functools
        getprime_func = functools.partial(parallel.getprime, poolsize=poolsize)
    else: getprime_func = rsa.prime.getprime
    (p, q, e, d) = gen_keys(nbits, getprime_func)
    n = p * q
    return (PublicKey(n, e), PrivateKey(n, e, d, p, q))
__all__ = ['PublicKey', 'PrivateKey', 'newkeys']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    try:
        for count in range(100):
            (failures, tests) = doctest.testmod()
            if failures:
                break
            if (count and count % 10 == 0) or count == 1:
                print('%i times' % count)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Aborted')
    else:
        print('Doctests done')
```

what's wrong here ?

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import rsa; print (dir(rsa)); print (rsa.__file__)"`?

Comment: same error as above @GregoryNisbet ..... i'm editing now

Comment: Did you install the python-rsa module through `pip` or by copying the file?

Comment: Can you try renaming your file in `H:\Work\Python-Django\Projects\RSA\rsa.py` to something else and running it again and seeing if the error changes? Also, what is your `rsa.py` file for? On the plus side, It looks like your `python-rsa` module was installed correctly and contains a `newkeys` method.

Comment: i want test this module first, then using it in my project ..... by renaming the file i haven't any error but many many many lines of description about functions of module that i can't understand any of them ..... oooooh :( @GregoryNisbet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98990/discussion-between-gregory-nisbet-and-arash-hatami).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as it turns out, you ran into a rather strange property of Python, namely that you can import the module of the current file. Your `rsa.py` file was shadowing the `rsa` directory (which contains an `__init__.py` file so it can be loaded as a module.)

Try making a file `foo.py` with the following contents

```
import foo

def bar():
    return 5

print dir(foo)
```

This will print something like

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'bar', 'foo']
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'bar', 'foo']
```

when you run `python foo.py`

It prints the directory structure twice (once when the module is loaded) and once when the file is evaluated.

This does *not* result in an infinite loop because Python caches modules that it has already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Gregory :

1- first thing , the *.py file name and imported module name can not be the same .... if we use the same name for them problem like mine will come. IDLE can not recognize the write way to run the file

2- there is a seriously problem in this module. when i want use **poolsize=x** parameter of **newkeys()** function i have many error and a big loop in my program. it's because multiprocessing of this module that not work in Windows 10. This problem can be caused by *Windows* or *module*.